# Create a dialog in UI Thread causes crash

Tags: c++, multithreading

I tried to create a dialog in a UI thread(CWinThread).
However, it crashes when the CDialog::Create() is called.
I had verified with previous implementation, the dialog is successfully created in non-threading mode.

Does any guru here know the crash reason of creating a dialog in CWinThread?

Without Threading:

```
class CProduction : public CDialog{
...
}
class CScrollProductionView : public CScrollView{
CProduction *m_pProduction;
...
}

void CScrollProductionView::OnInitialUpdate(){
   m_pProduction = new CProduction(0, *m_pVisionAdapter);
   m_pProduction->Create(IDD_DLG_PROD, this);  //--> created dialog successfully
   m_pProduction->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
}
```

Implement UI Thread:

```
class CProduction : public CDialog{
...
}
class CScrollProductionView : public CScrollView{
  CProductionThread* m_pProdThread;
  ...
}

class CProductionThread : public CWinThread{
   CProduction *m_pProduction;
   ...
}

void CScrollProductionView::OnInitialUpdate(){
   m_pProdThread->PostThreadMessage(WM_INITPRODTHREADMESSAGE, PROD_INIT, (LPARAM)m_pVisionAdapter);
   m_pProdThread->PostThreadMessage(WM_INITPRODTHREADMESSAGE, PROD_CREATE_DLG, (LPARAM)this);

 }

void CProductionThread::InitMessageHandler(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   printf("Receiving InitMessageHandler msg %d\n", (UINT)wParam);
   switch(wParam)
   {
    case PROD_INIT:
    {
      CVisionAdapter* pAdapter = (CVisionAdapter*)lParam;
      m_pProduction = new CProduction(NULL, *pAdapter);
    }
     break;
    case PROD_CREATE_DLG:
     {
      CScrollProductionView* pView = (CScrollProductionView*)lParam;
      m_pProduction->Create(IDD_DLG_PROD, pView);  //--> Crash here
      m_pProduction->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
     }
       break;
     default:
       break;
   }
}
```

Error message:

> Debug Assertion Failed!     ..
>   File: .... wincore.cpp
>   Line: 9906

Thanks you for viewing this question.

Comment: What is the assertion on line 9906 of your wincore.cpp? Often times the assertion code itself or a nearby comment give a big clue as to what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the problem is that your `CProduction` object has not been created when the `PROD_CREATE_DLG` message is being handled. This may be because of using `PostThreadMessage`. Using `PostThreadMessage` is fraught with problems. In particular, the messages may get lost, so the thread never sees the `PROD_INIT` message.

In the single-threaded code you create your `CProduction` object right before the `Create` call. Why don't you do the same in the multi-threaded code?

If you really want to use windows messages to communicate between your threads, I would create a "message only" window (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599.aspx#message_only) instead, as the window messages will not get lost in the same way that the thread messages do.

Alternatively, use a thread-safe queue to pass custom messages between threads, such as my example queue at http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html

Answer (score 3):

Try not to create CWinThread, instead of creating a worker thread, if you have many communication between classes like passing object pointers, strings etc.
You will feel less headache if update the GUI through message handling.

Answer (score 0):

The crash is caused by MFC referring invalid window handle (which passed in as parent) during creation.

> As a general rule, a thread can access
>   only MFC objects that it created. This
>   is because temporary and permanent
>   Windows handle maps are kept in thread
>   local storage to help maintain
>   protection from simultaneous access
>   from multiple threads.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h14y172e(VS.71).aspx

an easy fix stated in the MSDN involves changing the code into

```
...

m_pProdThread->PostThreadMessage(WM_INITPRODTHREADMESSAGE, PROD_CREATE_DLG, (LPARAM)this->GetSafeHwnd());

...

CScrollProductionView* pView = (CScrollProductionView*)CScrollProductionView::FromHandle((HWND)lParam);
m_pProduction->Create(IDD_DLG_PROD, pView);
m_pProduction->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

**Edit**: 
Fixed the link to msdn.

Comment: "If you have a multithreaded application that creates a thread in a way other than using a CWinThread object, you cannot access other MFC objects from that thread..." from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h14y172e(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: @wengseng, how does it turn out on your side? i'm able to simulate the crashing on my side, which is fixed after the posted modifications.